# How do I return to the user stream in flutter

Tags: flutter, stream, state-management

I'm having an issue return a Stream to a StreamBuilder widget in a flutter. I'm trying to access a custom class that is stored token.

```
class User {
  String token;
  User({this.token});
}
===============================

class AuthService {
  String url = 'https://reqres.in/api/login';
  String token = '';
// {
//   "email": "eve.holt@reqres.in",
//   "password": "cityslicka"
// }
  Map data;
  Future signIn(String email, String password) async {
    final response =
        await post(url, body: {'email': email, 'password': password});
    data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(data['token']);
    token = data['token'];
    _userFromDatabaseUser(data);
    return data;
  }
  //create user obj based on the database user
  User _userFromDatabaseUser(Map user) {
    return user != null ? User(token: user['token']) : null;
  }
  //user stream for provider
  Stream<User> get user {
    return  .................. ;
  }
```

Comment: A stream is a flow of data. You seem to not have any flow. You could certainly create a stream from your one value by using `Stream.value` but again, what is the point if your data is not a stream in the first place. What do you want your stream to represent?

Comment: @nvoigt I didn't get any value in a wrapper class. what should I do `code` class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget { @override Widget build(BuildContext context) { final user = Provider.of<User>(context); print(user); if (user == null) { return Authenticate(); } else { return Home(); } } } `code`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a stream controller:

```
class AuthService {
  final String url = 'https://reqres.in/api/login';
  final controller = StreamController<User>();

  Future<User> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    final response = await post(url, body: {'email': email, 'password': password});
    final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    final user = _userFromDatabaseUser(data);
    controller.add(user);
    return user;
  }

  //create user obj based on the database user
  User _userFromDatabaseUser(Map user) {
    return user != null ? User(token: user['token']) : null;
  }

  //user stream for provider
  Stream<User> get user {
    return controller.stream;
  }
```

Please note that this approach is a simplistic example that has some flaws, you should read up on it [in the documentation](https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams).

If you use this for the purpose you describe, you may want to look into the [bloc](/questions/tagged/bloc) pattern and it's implementation as [flutter-bloc](/questions/tagged/flutter-bloc). It might seem easier to do the user in this way by hand, but once you reach the point where you have multiple of those streams, you may want a more structured approach.

Comment: I didn't get any value in a wrapper class. what should I do @nvoigt ` class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    print(user);
    if (user == null) {
      return Authenticate();
    } else {
      return Home();
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use  
Stream<User> get user async*{
yield  .................. ;
}
```

you can use yield keyword when you want to return stream object.

```
2nd way you can use a stream controller. You can add value in controller and
listen wherever you want to listen in your app there is no need to return stream
```